# alert those textboxes who is still empty

Tags: javascript, php

```
function checkvalue() { 
    var areaDesc = document.getElementById('areaDesc').value;
    var cboLeaveType = document.getElementById('cboLeaveType').value;
    var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var toDate = document.getElementById('toDate').value;

    if (areaDesc == "" || fromDate == "" || toDate == "" || cboLeaveType = "")
    {            
        alert("empty hoys");            
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('hdnAction').value = "go";
        document.frmLeave.submit();
    }               
}
```

thats the code, it is working but, I want to alert those area who is still empty,

for example.

**ex1:** areaDesc, fromDate, toDate is not empty, it must alert "txtSignOff still empty";

**ex2:** areaDesc, fromDate is not empty it must alert "toDate,txtSignOff still empty";
or

toDate is empty

toDate is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to split your if block into individual ones, then use a String and concatenate it with the empty field's name in each if. That is,

```
var emptyStr = ''
if (areaDesc == '') { emptyStr += 'areaDesc,' ; }
if (fromDate == '') { emptyStr += 'fromDate,' ; }...
...
emptyStr += ' still empty'
if (emptyStr != '') { alert(emptyStr); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for in` like this:

```
function checkvalue() { 
    var fields = {
        'areaDesc' : document.getElementById('areaDesc').value;
        'cboLeaveType' : document.getElementById('cboLeaveType').value;
        'fromDate' : document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
        'toDate' : document.getElementById('toDate').value;
    };

    for(var fieldName in fields){
        if(fields[fieldName] == ""){
            alert("field" + fieldName + "is empty");
            return false;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('hdnAction').value = "go";
    document.frmLeave.submit();
}
```

Comment: doesnt work bro. it doesnt do anything after i call checkvalue();

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have an individual if statement for each input type you're requiring, otherwise it's a very generic error message. Something like this should do it:

Also, where is `txtSignOff` defined? Did you mean `cboLeaveType`?

If you don't want multiple alerts, just combine all the alerts from the code below and convert them into a string, and then `if (error)`, alert the error string.

```
function checkvalue() { 
    var areaDesc = document.getElementById('areaDesc').value;
    var cboLeaveType = document.getElementById('cboLeaveType').value;
    var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var toDate = document.getElementById('toDate').value;

    if (!areaDesc) alert("areaDesc still empty");
    if (!fromDate) alert("fromDate still empty");
    if (!toDate) alert("toDate still empty");
    if (!txtSignOff) alert("txtSignOff still empty");

    if (areaDesc && fromDate && toDate && txtSignOff)
    {
        document.getElementById('hdnAction').value = "go";
        document.frmLeave.submit();
    }
}
```